# SQL Error [8152] [22001]: String or binary data would be truncated while insertion

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

I have a SQL Server database table with the following structure

```
CREATE TABLE TableA
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    [NAME] varchar NOT NULL,
    [ORDER] [numeric](22, 0) NOT NULL,
    [VALUE] varchar NOT NULL,
    [VNAME] varchar NULL,
    [CREATOR] varchar NULL,
    [CREATION_DATE] datetime2 default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NULL,
    [MODIF_LAST] datetime2 default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_48_CODES] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(PersonID ASC)
               WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                     IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                     ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

When I try to execute the insert command I get the following error

> SQL Error [8152] [22001]: String or binary data would be truncated.

My insert command is as follows

```
INSERT INTO TableA (CODE_NAME, CODE_ORDER, VALUE, VALUE_NAME, CREATOR) 
VALUES ('CAP', 122, 'HIGH', 'SHIELD', 'H.STARK');
```

There are many duplicates of this particular error, but unfortunately none of them are working for me.

I am using DBeaver as my DB creation and viewing application.

I would really appreciate a help with this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length). In this case, the strings `'HIGH'`,`'SHIELD'`, and `'H.STARK'` are longer than 1 character, so would never fit in a `varchar` of length `1`.

Comment: Also, you try to `INSERT` into the columns `CODE_NAME` and `CODE_ORDER` in the table `TableA`; neither of which are defined in your DDL.

Answer (score 6):

*Always* use a length with `varchar()`:

```
VALUE varchar(255) NOT NULL,
VNAME varchar(255) NULL,
```

The default length varies by context -- and it might not be big enough to store the values you want.  In this example, the default length is `1`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time.. That helped!!